# How to synchronize version control system revisions with Docker image versions?

Tags: deployment, version-control, continuous-integration, docker

What is a common, conventional pattern for associating Docker image versions in Docker registry and Git (for example) revisions? So user of repository will be able to switch at any revision and recreate environment that corresponds to that specific revision.

For example I have a repository with a project and integration server which automatically builds Docker images for every commit in repository. How these images can be tied to corresponding repository commits?

Using Docker you have two different repositories - with a project and with Docker images - so they must be synchronized, but what are recommended workflows for this?

Answer (score 5):

Docker Hub supports two types of repos, and you haven't said which kind you are using. In both cases, I would suggest you put the git revision or tag name in the version portion of the image name, e.g. "account/repo:**version**"

### Manual Repository (`docker push`)

For manual builds, you should `docker tag` each version with the git revision. This is the recommended method because it gives you the most control and can be automated on your build system.

### Automated Build Repository

For automated builds on the Docker Hub, you will need to manually create a new entry for each revision or tag you want built. This requires going to the Hub web UI and creating a new build configuration for your repo, as pictured below. There is no API at this time which allows you to change build settings on your repo, nor does the automated build system automatically add Docker Hub tags when you add tags to your Git Hub repo.

**Note** at this time (2014-10-07) there is a bug where the automated builds do not actually build from tags in your source code repository, they build from head of master branch. The status is shown on https://status.docker.com

---

Here is how to add a build configuration to an automated build:

[image]

Comment: That's the way to go.

Comment: "For automated builds you will need to manually create a new build" - what do you mean - "manually"? Can you describe this step-by-step? Why not automate image building process?

Comment: I think Andy simply means to say that you run `docker build` in your automated build process. This depends greatly on what you actually want to build. Maybe your build process builds every git push, or builds a set of git tags, etc..

Comment: Added screenshot of "manually creating a new build" and made some other clarifications and a warning about an open bug.

Comment: @Andy Oh, I get it. Thanks for detailed answer, by the way. After some thinking I came to conclusion, that it is wrong to label Docker images with SCM revision, because image must not be changed with each revision. Each image obviously has its own revision line, and hence must be versioned separately. I think its better to just label each image like `1.0`, `1.1` manually in a `Dockerfile`. But it seems that `Dockerfile` does not support this kind of versioning.